# How do I update a column named Date in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-update, exasol

I have a table that has a column named Date. This causes problems because Date is a data type name. I tried the following statements to escape it:

```
Update Tables.Subtable SET `Date` = "2022-03-14 07:20:32"  WHERE ID=960646;
Update Tables.Subtable SET "Date" = "2022-03-14 07:20:32"  WHERE ID=960646;

Update Tables.Subtable SET Tables.Subtable."Date" = "2022-03-14 07:20:32"  WHERE ID=960646;
Update Tables.Subtable SET Tables.Subtable.`Date` = "2022-03-14 07:20:32"  WHERE ID=960646;

Update Tables.Subtable SET Subtable."Date" = "2022-03-14 07:20:32"  WHERE ID=960646;
Update Tables.Subtable SET Subtable.`Date` = "2022-03-14 07:20:32"  WHERE ID=960646;
```

All of them caused an error. What is the right syntax here?

Comment: `SET Tables.Subtable."Date" = DATE'2022-03-14 07:20:32'`, or perhaps `SET Tables.Subtable."Date" = '2022-03-14 07:20:32'`.

Comment: If you are using sql server, use `[Date]`. Avoid naming the column as such.

Comment: `date` is a SQL reserved word, and therefore needs to be delimited if used as an identifier. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words

Comment: PLEASE include the actual error messages when you ask this type of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your date literal being delimited by double quotes. This should work:

```
Update Tables.Subtable SET "Date" = '2022-03-14 07:20:32'  WHERE ID=960646;
```

Comment: Which is in the manual... https://docs.exasol.com/db/latest/sql_references/literals.htm#DateTimeLiterals

Comment: I get the error: [Code: 0, SQL State: 42000]  object "Date" not found [line 2, column 35] (Session: 1727260684604729758)  [Script position: 137 - 138]

but this one works:

`select * from Table.Subtable order by Table.Subtable."DATE" desc limit 4 `

So the column "Date" should acutally exist, right?

Comment: @Roman27 Make sure that you use the correct capitalization of "Date". Identifiers inside double quotes are case sensitive!

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are using MS SQL Server...

First, SQL identifier AKA name of tables, columns, routines, constraints... must apply the standard SQL rules that says :

- use only figures and pure latin letters (without accent...) and the underscore character
- do not begin by a figure
- lenght must be 128 characters maximum
- try to do not use SQL keywords ("table', 'column", "date"...) except if the name is surrounded of double quote

So, a column nammed Date must be surround of double quote and that works perfectly in SQL Server

```
SELECT "Date", ...
```

Some RDBMS add a specific surround technic. In SQL Server you can use squared brackets to do so...

```
SELECT [Date], ...
```

Another trouble in you query can be the datetime format.

If the column use a DATETIME datatype which is not recommanded, the only date and time format supported whatever the settings of the session, is the short SQL ISO format that is :

```
'AAAAMMJJ hh:mm:ss.nnn'
```

You can execute this text to convince you :

```
SET LANGUAGE French;

SELECT CAST('2022-12-31 23:59:58' AS datetime) AS "Date";

--> Msg 242, Niveau 16, État 3, Ligne 3 La conversion d'un type de données varchar en type de données datetime a créé une valeur hors limites.

SET LANGUAGE English;

SELECT CAST('2022-12-31 23:59:58' AS datetime) AS "Date";

Date
-----------------------
2022-12-31 23:59:58.000
```

This firts test shows that for some languages, this format (Long SQL ISO) is unacceptable.

But when you use the short SQL ISO format, no trouble...

```
SET LANGUAGE French;

SELECT CAST('20221231 23:59:58' AS datetime) AS "Date";

Date
-----------------------
2022-12-31 23:59:58.000

SET LANGUAGE English;

SELECT CAST('20221231 23:59:58' AS datetime) AS "Date";

Date
-----------------------
2022-12-31 23:59:58.000
```

When using datatype DATE, DATETIME2, DATETIMEOFFSET, TIME, the only format that is supported whatever the settings of the session is, called long SQL ISO, relies on 'AAAA-MM-JJ hh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn'. For some compatability reasons with XML, the standard XML datetime format is also supported 'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn'

AS you can see in my test :

```
SET LANGUAGE French;

SELECT CAST('2022-12-31 23:59:58' AS datetime2) AS "Date";

SET LANGUAGE English;

SELECT CAST('2022-12-31 23:59:58' AS datetime2) AS "Date";
```

Now the two SQL statement works properly...

**NOTE** : the .nnn... parts is not required and the scale can be smaller.

**Why two formats ?** One (short SQL ISO) for DATETIME / SMALLDATETIME and the second (long SQL format)... Because the SQL ISO standard evolves by the time. The firts format was done for the SQL 2 (1992) of the SQL ISO Standard. The second one when SQL:1999 has been release. DATETIME and SMALDATETIME was inherited from Sybase at the end of the eighties. DATETIME2, DATE and DATTIME offset was relase in SQL Server 2008...